# How to click on element having both string and random number using selenium javascript

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<a id="Message4217" class="btn-sm btn-danger Message" data-id="4217"><span class="icon-adjustment icon-trash"></span> Delete</a>
```

1. Goal is to delete a message based on the selection criteria
2. For every message, it has **text** and a random number (i.e) `"Message4217"`
3. How can we select and click for random numbers
4. I am not able to use `xpath` because every different message generates random numbers

   ```
   //*[@id="Message4217"]

   //*[@id="Message4218"]
   ```
5. Is there a way to select such type of elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use this **xpath**:

```
//a[starts-with(@id,'Message')]
```

or the below **css**:

```
a[id^='Message']
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath/css` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

if there are let's say nth matches then you can use `findElements` with the XPath of CSS and then can iterate or use the index to click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this element can be located based on 2 parameters:

1. The partial `id` value
2. The text

If so it will match this XPath:

```
//a[contains(@id,'Message') and text()='Delete']
```

There is a `span` element inside it, we can add this dependency as well so the locator will be:

```
//a[contains(@id,'Message') and text()='Delete' and ./span[@class='icon-adjustment icon-trash']]
```